Father is part of the Quranist movement
Quranism is an Islamic movement that holds the belief that the Quran is the only valid source of religious belief, guidance and law in Islam. Quranists believe that the Quran is clear, complete, and that it can be fully understood without recourse to the hadith and sunnah. My father adheres to the Quranism movement, which rejects the Hadith of the Prophet (pbuh) and does not pray, leading some to label him as a KAAFIR in Islamic tradition, a view with which I concur. My mother remains married to him. Is it necessary for her to seek divorce, and if so, how should I approach discussing this with her?

Akhi, I cannot answer this as I do not have the relevant credentials to determine if the kufr of the father requires divorce between the parents, but this is truly a sad situation to be in. It is a test from Allah. Try to do dawah to your father and bring him back as well. May Allah ease your affairs and have his mercy upon you, Aameen.

Does this answer your question? Does the marriage of a man who leaves Islam remain valid? , For not praying see https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32787/

We are not a fatwa site, nor do we give advice on personal situations - consult a Mufti.
